# Lint possible access / creation out of bounds pointer

Tags: c++, lint

I get a Lint warning 661 / 662. They mean possible access / creation of out-of-bounds pointer. But I do check the boundaries and it is not possible to be out of bounds. Any ideas how to get rid of it?

```
const my_enum_type my_array[] = {MY_FIRST_ENUM_VALUE, MY_SECOND_ENUM_VALUE, MY_THIRD_ENUM_VALUE};  
for(i = 0; i < sizeof(my_array); i++){ 
    //do stuff such as
    my_variable = my_array[i];
    my_function(my_array[i]);
}
```

The lines where I use `my_array[i]` are complaining with code 661 / 662.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sizeof` returns the number of bytes, not the elements, so I guess the error is valid.
Use `sizeof(my_array) / sizeof(my_array[0])` to get the element count.

Answer (score 6):

`sizeof(my_array)` is not what you want. You want `sizeof(my_array) / sizeof(*my_array)`.

You may use iterator:

```
for(auto it = std::begin(my_array); it != std::end(my_array); ++it){ 
    //do stuff such as
    my_variable = *it;
    my_function(*it);
}
```

or directly for range:

```
for (const auto& e : my_array){ 
    //do stuff such as
    my_variable = e;
    my_function(e);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`sizeof(my_array)` does not return the number of elements in the array, it returns the size in bytes of the array.

The traditional C way of getting the size is `sizeof(my_array) / sizeof(my_array[0])` but the safer C++11 way is to use [std::extent](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/extent) from <[type_traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits)>:

```
std::extent<decltype(my_array)>::value
```

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(myarray)`  returns size in bytes of the object representation. So not number of items in array, but whole array size. If `sizeof(my_enum_type) > 1` `i` will go outside bounds.

Try `sizeof(myarray) / sizeof(my_enum_type)`